# Warren's distinction between moral humanity and genetic humanity

Tags: ethics, abortion

Explain Warren's distinction between moral humanity and genetic humanity. What, according to Warren, are the 5 criteria for being considered of being a moral person. And why does she maintain that the active presence and not merely the potentiality of these five criteria is sufficient and necessary for constituting a moral person?

Comment: +1 Here is a link that lists the five criteria: http://www.csus.edu/indiv/g/gaskilld/ethics/abortion.htm

Comment: Warren's article is reproduced here : http://www.douglasficek.com/teaching/phil-2222/warren.pdf

Comment: You will have to do your homework on your own. This reads an aweful lot like essay coursework.

Comment: For whom interested https://writerforlife.medium.com/universal-logic-for-humanity-1d79b5b59c40